# How to make the file: /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server editable(writable)?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am in process to set up a DHCP server on Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.

I need to edit the file:  /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

How can I make it editable and save after applying necessary changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ SUDO_EDITOR=/path/to/text-editor sudoedit /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
```

From the [sudo(8) manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sudo.8.html):

> When invoked as `sudoedit`, the `-e` option (described below), is implied.
>
> […]
>
> The `-e` (edit) option indicates that, instead of running a command, the user
>   wishes to edit one or more files.
>
> […]
>
> 1. Temporary copies are made of the files to be edited with the owner set
>      to the invoking user.
> 2. The editor specified by the policy is run to edit the temporary files.
>      The `sudoers` policy uses the `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` and `EDITOR`
>      environment variables (in that order).  […]
> 3. If they have been modified, the temporary files are copied back to their
>      original location and the temporary versions are removed.